# how to add number to field in every document in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My collection has a `phonenumber` field. I want to add 91 in front of phonenumber.

```
{
"_id": "6137392141bbb7723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":9000000001
},
{
"_id": "6137392141bbe30723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":9000000002
}
```

I want to update my collection like this.

```
{
"_id": "6137392141bbb7723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":919000000001
},
{
"_id": "6137392141bbe30723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":919000000002
}
```

I'm trying with this code but it's not updating the field.

```
var x = await User.find({});
        x.forEach(async function(d)
            { 
                var phone = d.phonenumber;  
                var newPhoneNumber = 910000000000+phone;
                console.log(newPhoneNumber);

                //update 
            await User.updateMany({},{$set:{phonenumber:newPhoneNumber}},
                {
                    new: true, 
                    runValidators : true
                });
            })
```

I'm getting only one value for all documents like this:

```
{
"_id": "6137392141bbb7723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":919000000001
},
{
"_id": "6137392141bbe30723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":919000000001
},
{
"_id": "6137392141bbe30723",
"email": "brooke@cagle.com",
"lastname": "Cagle",
"firstname": "Brooke",
"phonenumber":919000000001
}
```

I don't know whether this approach is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H5iEtjgomxS)

```
db.collection.update({},
//To match all documents
[{
  $set: {
    key: {
      $toInt: {
        $concat: [
          "91",
          {
            $toString: "$key"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
],
//Concatenate 91 and the value in the field
{multi: true
})
```

This is applicable for mongo versions from 4.2. This is aggregation pipeline which is used in update query.

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update)

EDIT:

You would have got overFlow error. You could use toLong in this case.

```
db.mybooks.update({},
//To match all documents
[{
  $set: {
    key: {
      $toLong: {
        $concat: [
          "91",
          {
            $toString: "$key"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
],
//Concatenate 91 and the value in the field
{multi: true
})
```

It's tested piece of code.

Comment: $concat only works on strings not on numbers. thank you!

Comment: @saikrishna check the edit please.

Comment: above code  is also not working.Thank you!

Comment: @saikrishna What is the mongo version are you using? Not working - in the sense?

Comment: Try out the latest code please

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Maybe, this works,

```
let mobile = 9876543210;
let phone = `91${mobile}`;
let final = Number(phone)
console.log(typeof(final), final+3);
```

So,

```
var phone = d.phonenumber;
var newPhoneNumber = Number(`91${phone}`);
console.log(newPhoneNumber);
```

Read more about Number() : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).